# AngularJs, How to edit $scope values in other div using the same controller with factory

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to use two different divs one contains a form and other contains repeat for the $scope values. Those two divs needs to use the same controller. However I am not able to share data in between divs in a desired way. Although I use factory, it only helps for me to add data to scope. I also want to edit the scope values inside the form which has another instance of the same controller. 
You can find what I did in [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FCG9H9X8N0HT).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<body>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []);
app.factory('fact',function(){
    products = ["milk","chese"];
    tempItem = '';
    tempIndex = undefined;
    return {
        getProducts : function() {
            return products;
        },
        getProductByIndex : function(x){
            return products[x];
        },
        saveProduct : function(x,item)
        {
            if(x==undefined)
            {
                products.push(item);
            }
            else
            {
                products[x] = item;
            }
            tempItem = '';
            tempIndex = undefined;
        },
        editProduct : function(x)
        {
            tempItem = products[x];
            tempIndex = x;
        },
        removeProduct : function(x)
        {
            products.splice(x, 1);
        },
        getTempItem : function()
        {
            return tempItem;
        },
        getTempIndex : function()
        {
            return tempIndex;
        },
    }
}); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, fact) {
    $scope.products = fact.getProducts();
    $scope.tempIndex = fact.getTempIndex();
    $scope.tempItem = fact.getTempItem();
    $scope.saveItem = function () {
        fact.saveProduct($scope.tempIndex,$scope.tempItem);
    }
    $scope.editItem = function (x) {
        fact.editProduct(x);
    }
    $scope.removeItem = function (x) {
        fact.removeProduct(x);
    }
});

</script>

<div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-cloak class="w3-card-2 w3-margin" style="max-width:400px;">
  <header class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-padding-16">
    <h3>My Shopping List</h3>
  </header>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul class="w3-ul">
    <li ng-repeat="x in products" class="w3-padding-16">{{$index}} {{x}}
    <span ng-click="editItem($index)" style="cursor:pointer;" class="w3-right w3-margin-right">||</span>
    <span ng-click="removeItem($index)" style="cursor:pointer;" class="w3-right w3-margin-right">×</span>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl"  class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-padding-16">
  <form ng-submit="saveItem()">
    <div class="w3-row w3-margin-top">
      <div class="w3-col s10">
        <input placeholder="Add shopping items here" ng-model="tempItem" class="w3-input w3-border w3-padding">
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="tempIndex">
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col s2">
        <button type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-padding w3-green">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ISSUES**

- You have initialized controller twice.
- You can do edit item inside controller itself.
- After saving $scope values should be cleared along with clearing values in factory.

---

*CONTROLLER and HTML*

```js
var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []);
app.factory('fact',function(){
 products = ["milk","chese"];
    tempItem = '';
    tempIndex = undefined;
    return {
     getProducts : function() {
         return products;
        },
        getProductByIndex : function(x){
         return products[x];
        },
        saveProduct : function(x,item)
        {
            if(!x)
            {
    products.push(item);
            }
            else
            {
    products[x] = item;
            }
            tempItem = '';
         tempIndex = '';
        },
        editProduct : function(x)
        {
          tempItem = products[x];
            tempIndex = x;
        },
        removeProduct : function(x)
        {
           products.splice(x, 1);
        },
        getTempItem : function()
        {
         return tempItem;
        },
        getTempIndex : function()
        {
         return tempIndex;
        },
    }
}); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, fact) {
    $scope.products = fact.getProducts();
    $scope.tempIndex = fact.getTempIndex();
    $scope.tempItem = fact.getTempItem();
    $scope.saveItem = function () {
  fact.saveProduct($scope.tempIndex,$scope.tempItem);
        $scope.tempItem = '';
        $scope.tempIndex = '';
    }
    $scope.editItem = function (x) {
     $scope.tempItem = fact.getProducts()[x];
        $scope.tempIndex = x;
    }
    $scope.removeItem = function (x) {
        fact.getProducts().splice(x, 1);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-cloak class="w3-card-2 w3-margin" style="max-width:400px;">
  <header class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-padding-16">
    <h3>My Shopping List</h3>
  </header>
  <div>
  <ul class="w3-ul">
    <li ng-repeat="x in products" class="w3-padding-16">{{$index}} {{x}}
    <span ng-click="editItem($index)" style="cursor:pointer;" class="w3-right w3-margin-right">||</span>
    <span ng-click="removeItem($index)" style="cursor:pointer;" class="w3-right w3-margin-right">×</span>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-padding-16">
  <form ng-submit="saveItem()">
    <div class="w3-row w3-margin-top">
      <div class="w3-col s10">
        <input placeholder="Add shopping items here" ng-model="tempItem" class="w3-input w3-border w3-padding">
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="tempIndex">
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col s2">
        <button type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-padding w3-green">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```